# Google map's weather layer not appearing but traffic is

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Hey guys I'm trying to add in different layer for my map but I ran into some trouble with the weather layer.When I add the traffic layer by itself the map works but when I add the weather layer only a gray box where the map should have been appears. Any help will be great thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="Description" content="Get ready to experience Indianapolis! This site will make your visit the best one yet!"/>
<title>The Indy Tour- Travel</title>
<link href="../style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,700,400italic,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyA6VosQrKQOjoTbDSp4Kk4BHvofOJFUfZU&sensor=true"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var map;
        function initialize() { 
            var myOptions = {
            zoom: 9,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };

        var all = [
            ["Indianapolis International Airport", "7800 Col. H. Weir Cook Memorial Drive", "Indianapolis", "IN", "46241", "null", "null", "airport"],          
            ["Indianapolis International Airport", "7800 Col. H. Weir Cook Memorial Drive", "Indianapolis", "IN", "46241", "39.71449", "-86.29842", "airport"], 
            ["Location 2", "7205 Olmstead Dr", "Burlington", "NC", "27215", "36.069974", "-79.548101", "airport",],
            ["Location 3", "W Market St", "Graham", "NC", "27253", "36.0722225", "-79.4016207", "resturant"],
            ["Location 4", "Mt Hermon Rock Creek Rd", "Graham", "NC", "27253", "35.9826328", "-79.4165216", "hotel"],
            ["Location 5", "415 Spring Garden St", "Greensboro", "NC", "27401", "36.06761", "-79.794984", "hotel"]
        ];

        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), myOptions);

        var trafficLayer = new google.maps.TrafficLayer();
  trafficLayer.setMap(map);
  var weatherLayer = new google.maps.weather.WeatherLayer({
  temperatureUnits: google.maps.weather.TemperatureUnit.CELSIUS
});
weatherLayer.setMap(map);

var cloudLayer = new google.maps.weather.CloudLayer();
cloudLayer.setMap(map);  


        var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(39.76656, -86.15);
        map.setCenter(pos);

        function infoCallback(infowindow, marker) { 
            return function() {
            infowindow.open(map, marker);

        };



   }            
   function setMarkers(map, all) {  
    for (var i in all) {                                        
            var name    = all[i][0];
            var address = all[i][1];
            var city    = all[i][2];
            var state   = all[i][3];
            var zip     = all[i][4];
            var lat     = all[i][5];
            var lng     = all[i][6];
            var image   = all[i][7];
            var latlngset;
            latlngset = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

            var icon=null;
            if  (image=="airport") {
                icon=airport;
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({  
                map: map,  title: city,  position: latlngset, icon: icon, shadow: shadow
            });
            }
            else if (image=="hotel") {
                icon=hotel;
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({  
                map: map,  title: city,  position: latlngset, icon: icon, shadow: shadow
            });
            }
            else if (image=="resturant") {
                icon=resturant;
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({  
                map: map,  title: city,  position: latlngset, icon: icon, shadow: shadow
            });
            }

            var airport = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
            '../images/airport.png',
            new google.maps.Size(32,37),
            new google.maps.Point(0,0),
            new google.maps.Point(16,37)
            );
             var hotel = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
            '../images/hotel.png',
            new google.maps.Size(32,37),
            new google.maps.Point(0,0),
            new google.maps.Point(16,37)
            );
            var resturant = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
            '../images/resturant.png',
            new google.maps.Size(32,37),
            new google.maps.Point(0,0),
            new google.maps.Point(16,37)
            );
            var shadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
            '../images/shadow.png',
            new google.maps.Size(54,37),
            new google.maps.Point(0,0),
            new google.maps.Point(16,37)
            );
            var content = '<div class="map-content"><h3>' + name + '</h3>' + address + '<br />' + city + ', ' + state + ' ' + zip + '<br /><a href="http://maps.google.com/?daddr=' + address + ' ' + city + ', ' + state + ' ' + zip + '" target="_blank">Get Directions</a></div>';                   
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
              infowindow.setContent(content);
              google.maps.event.addListener(
                marker, 
                'click', 
                infoCallback(infowindow, marker)
              );
          }
        }           
        setMarkers(map, all);
      };
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="logo">
    <div id="wrap">
        <div id="header">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="../index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="History.html">History</a></li>
                <li><a href="Attractions.html">Attractions</a></li>
                <li><a href="Landmarks.html">Landmarks</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" style="color:#F60; text-decoration:underline;">Travel</a></li>
            </ul>
      </div>

        <div id="content">
            <h1 id="title">Travel</h1>
            <div id="map_canvas"></div>
            <img id="line" alt="footer" src="../images/footer.png"/>
            <div id="footer">
                    <ul id="ftext">
                    <li><a href="About.html">About the Team and Site</a></li>
                    <li><p style="display:inline;">Created 2012-2013 for BPA.</p></li>
                    <li><a href="Credits.html">Credits</a></li>
                </ul>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the weatherLayer requires the weather-library which is not loaded by default.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" 
    src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=weather&key=AIzaSyA6VosQrKQOjoTbDSp4Kk4BHvofOJFUfZU&sensor=true"></script>
```

Comment: Can't believe I missed soemthign so obvious, Thanks!